# "Attachment is not defined" in javascript code for discord bot (using discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, attachment, discord.js

Making some of my first attempts at functionality for a discord bot. I've copied and pasted code directly from an example in the discord.js documentation, and I'm running into an error.

Code:

```
if (message.content === '!rip') {
            // Create the attachment using Attachment
            const attachment = new Attachment('https://i.imgur.com/w3duR07.png');
            // Send the attachment in the message channel
            message.channel.send(attachment);
        }
```

Error Message:

```
ReferenceError: Attachment is not defined
    at Client.bot.on.message (C:\Code\ACCBot\bot.js:36:28)
    at Client.emit (events.js:194:15)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Code\ACCBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Code\ACCBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:105:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Code\ACCBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Code\ACCBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Code\ACCBot\node_modules\discord.js\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Code\ACCBot\node_modules\discord.js\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:789:20)
    at Receiver.emit (events.js:189:13)
```

The error occurs when I type !rip

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [Discord.JS Docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome), you can see in the [docs for Attachment](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Attachment), that the constructor for an attachment is defined as `new Discord.Attachment(file, name);` (where name is an optional argument). Your issue is that you are not defining Attachment as an object of the Discord object, where `Discord` is defined as `const Discord = require('discord.js');`

Comment: Glad i could help :)